# How to use a chronometer and properly update variables in a fragment?

Tags: android, variables, android-fragments, chronometer

**My scenario:**

I have three fragments in one activity, the activity switches between the fragments using a bottom menu. In the first fragment are multiple views including buttons, textViews and a chronometer. The second fragment mainly displays data (textViews, ProgressBars, ...).

In the first fragment the data displayed in the textViews is updated through public functions (in the fragment) that are being called from the activity.
Like this:

```
public void updateData(int data) {
    dataTextView.setText(String.valueOf(data));
}
```

On the other hand the second fragment gets (at the moment) its data through the initialization, like this:

```
public static SecondFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share, container, false);
    //find views and set data
    return v;
}
```

What I use to switch between the fragments:

```
private void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**My Issues:**

- The chronometer in the first fragment stops working when switching
  between the fragments
- I am not sure how to update the variables in the second fragment out of the activity (tried calling a method to update variables, but did not work) **UPDATE:** I am trying to update the text of multiple textViews and perform similar updates

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using Viewpager to switch between bottom navigation? You can try the setUserVisibleHint() and getUserVisibleHint() method to perform the update of Variables in Fragment.

Comment: I just added the method that I use to switch between the fragments

Comment: These methods will help you to get Action on Fragment Visibility to the user, So you can make update the Data by this method.

`@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { 
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isFragVisible = isVisibleToUser;

    if (isFragVisible) { 
        updateData(data)
    } /*else {  
        Log.d(localTAG, "this fragment is now invisible");
    }*/
}`

Comment: What does this method do? I am not sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: When you switch between Fragments this method will be called every time so you can make some operation here in this method also, So you can check if Fragment UI is visible to the user then Update the data and according to action. You can learn more [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#setuservisiblehint)

Comment: The method should be placed in a fragment, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176600/discussion-between-hector-morris-and-jonasxd360).